# calling request.setattribute in Spring validator interface

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-validator

How to access `request.setattribute` inside spring custom `validator` class. i need to set these values in `jsp` side I am trying something like below

```
@Component
public class ProductSearchValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Product.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);  
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Product product = (Product) target;
        String name = product.getName();
        String cod="Validated";

        request.setAttribute("isVal",cod);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to set that within the validator?

Comment: I am using these values in JSP hidden fields for some calculation purposes.

Comment: Not sure how that is related. What is calling your validator? Are you using it in a controller method? If so why not validate your target which will add errors as necessary and then in your controller check errors and add to the request as necessary. You can certainly do what StanislavL has provided but I personally would reconsider the need to access the request specifically within the validator

Answer (score 0):

You can access  request this way

```
RequestAttributes attrs = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
if (attrs instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)attrs).getRequest();
}
```